# jOOQ Insert into multiple tables from select

Tags: java, oracle, jooq

I need help with jooq DSL. How can be written in jooq DSL insert like this one

```sql
INSERT ALL
INTO table1
  (tid, date, title) values (s_tid, s_date, s_title)
INTO table2
  (tid, date, user, note) values (s_tid, s_date, s_user, s_note)
SELECT s_tid, s_date, s_title, s_user, s_note
FROM
( 
    SELECT 
        1 s_tid,
        '01-JAN-15' s_date,
        'title' s_title,
        'john' s_user,
        'test note' s_note
    FROM table3;
)
```

For Oracle SQL dialect.

Thanks

Comment: Why use `INSERT ALL` why not use `INSERT INTO table1 (tid, date, title) values (1, DATE '2015-01-01', 'title'); INSERT INTO table2 (tid, date, user, note) VALUES (1, DATE '2015-01-01', 'john', 'test_note');`? Which I am sure is much easier to convert.

Answer (score 2):

jOOQ 3.19 doesn't support this Oracle specific statement yet, see:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8237

You'll have to use [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) to run this query via jOOQ, or alternatively, run 2 separate `INSERT .. SELECT` statements.